# .find() vs. .siblings() to sift through AJAX results

Tags: jquery, ajax, find, siblings

In the below code, why does `$(data).find('#');` return null where as `$(data).siblings('#');` does work properly?

```
$.get("post.php", function(data) {  

    var new_data = $(data).find('#main_wrapper').html();
    console.log(new_data); // returns NULL

    var new_data = $(data).siblings('#main_wrapper').html();
    console.log(new_data);  // returns all of the html inside #main_wrapper
                            // like you'd expect it to.  shown below.
                            // <div class="container" id="content"><div class="popup"><div class="latest"><h2>News</h2></div></div></div>

});
```

[post.php is pasted in the pastebin here.](http://pastebin.com/w1rQ25ky)

Comment: Without actually seeing what is returned we'd only be speculating.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I updated the comment so it makes more sense.  I already had the post.php file pastebined, so you could see the proper HTML for yourself.  The other result returned NULL, which is not true.

Comment: We try to get as much posted here as possible @JacobRaccuia so that it is preserved for those who may visit SO in the future seeking answers.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've added the HTML just in case Pastebin goes down or the file is lost. Would you like me to add all of post.php as well?

Comment: you should only post what is relevant to your problem, then setup a pastebin or fiddle to illustrate the issue if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let first note the main difference between siblings and find. Find search for descendant while sibling get same level nodes.

Knowing that should give you insight on what the problem is, right?

Well, `.find` will not find your element if has no parent while `.siblings` will not find any element that has parents.

**ALSO**, if there is only 1 element on the root of your data, sibling will return 0 element.

An infallible solution is to append your data to a fake DOM element like that :

```
$myWrapper = $('<div>').html(data).find('#main_wrapper');
```

Comment: so what are the `html` and `body` tags considered, if not parents?

Comment: @JacobRaccuia `html`, `head` and `body` are stripped out when parsing the element with `$()`. Try it, see in the log what is the result of `console.log($(data));`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jc1YDtL.png is what I get.  I think I saw this in the past and ignored it.  This would have been so much faster to debug if it actually did show it stripped and not with everything else.

Comment: Well I don't understand what I posted above, so I haven't learned yet!  Where in that object does it show the stripped code?

Comment: @JacobRaccuia if it wasnt stripped, your object would have been only 1 element, the `html` one. Instead, it take only the content element. In fact, it's like if jquery did `$(head,body).contents();` with your data.